# BitmapFactory.Options returns null

Tags: java, android

I tried so many ways but I couldn't return the bitmap image from cache, it always return null bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap readBitMap(String fileName) {
    Bitmap bitmapFromCache = BitmapCacheUtil.getInstance().getBitmapFromCache(fileName);
    if (null != bitmapFromCache) {
        return bitmapFromCache;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    opt.inPurgeable = true;
    opt.inInputShareable = true;
    opt.inSampleSize = 1;
    bitmapFromCache = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, opt);
    BitmapCacheUtil.getInstance().addBitmapToCache(fileName, bitmapFromCache);
    return bitmapFromCache;
}
```

Comment: The complaint in your post does not match the one in the subject of your post.

Comment: And it is unclear how often you call that function. Scenario please.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help, i'm assuming the fileName as path

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sd+filePath, imageName);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName ,bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
return butmap;
```